# Is there a way to parse out the text, POST WINERY, POST WINERY, INC., in the HTML code below? How would I select this element?

Tags: web-scraping

Below is the HTML code that I'm trying to parse the winery name from. In this case I want to parse out POST WINERY, POST WINERY INC.

```html
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2">BW-AR-106</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2">POST WINERY, POST WINERY, INC.</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2">1700  SAINT MARYS MOUNTAIN RD</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2">ALTUS,&nbsp;AR&nbsp;72821</td>
        </tr>
    
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: What is the URL to the actual page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, theoretically, but if this is the actual HTML it will be a little dicey.  It will depend on having the part you want to get always be in exactly the same place, and in my experience that's not as likely to happen as you might think.

The only thing you have to work with is that it's in the second td element.  We can get those with querySelectorAll, and then just output the text of the second one.  You didn't specify what you're using to parse it, so I'm using javascript here, primarily because I can insert working javascript into the answer itself.

```js
let tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
console.log(tds[1].innerText);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="2">BW-AR-106</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">POST WINERY, POST WINERY, INC.</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">1700  SAINT MARYS MOUNTAIN RD</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">ALTUS,&nbsp;AR&nbsp;72821</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

But if there is more structure in the actual HTML that would probably be helpful.